# Is there a default controller for the index page for a CakePHP installation?

Tags: cakephp

I have just successfully installed CakePHP and I see that I can edit the `home.ctp` view but is there a default controller for the index page?

```
To change the content of this page, create: APP/views/pages/home.ctp.
To change its layout, create: APP/views/layouts/default.ctp.
You can also add some CSS styles for your pages at: APP/webroot/css.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the default controller is PagesController, located in:

```
cake/libs/controller/pages_controller.php
```

Comment: I think this answer is kind of dangerous, but as this is the first result on Google, I thought I would clarify a 3 year old answer. The file cake/libs/controller/pages_controller.php is part of the core source and any changes made to core files will be overwritten when updating the source. Changing the route (Tarik's answer) abstracts the issue by way of configuration and it is a valid option. CakePHP, however, runs a convention over configuration ethos so as a matter of best practice it's actually Hectors solution that should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to make modifications to this controller it is recommended that you copy the default

`cake/libs/controller/pages_controller.php to app/controller/pages_controller.php`

The reason is because you should not modify anything inside the "cake" folder where any file can be overwriten when updating your application with the latest cakephp version.

Comment: In CakePHP 2.1 and up, PagesController.php is included in the app/Controller folder (instead of the core folder) and no longer part of the core source.

Answer (score 13):

You can change the default behavior by changing the `Route::connect()` function arguments such as below:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'requests', 'action' => 'index', 'home'));
```

and also if you want to connect all the actions to one action, use the code below in the same config file:

```
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

Of course you should change the arguments to your own needs.

This configuration is located under `app/config/routes.php`.

To get more information about `Route::connect()`, visit this page: http://api.cakephp.org/class/router#method-Routerconnect